# Password Reset via SMS

Tags: password

Is it possible to send the Password reset email via SMS instead of email? I'm signing users up using their mobiles and a 6 digit pin + a randomly generated email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not natively, but there are some SMS related plugins for Craft 3 that might be useful.

https://github.com/bertoost/Craft-3-Mailjet

https://github.com/bertoost/Craft-3-Messagebird

Otherwise, you're looking at a custom developed plugin specific to your needs.